# How can I add text boxes to multiple pictures in one illustration in Inkscape at once?

Tags: inkscape, text, illustration, batch-processing, academic-publishing

I use Inkscape to create illustration for a "scientific paper". In this example I have 9 pictures in one illustration and I now want to add a small annotation (A-I) to each picture in the top left corner.

Is there a better way to do this than creating a new text box, writing the letter and then using the align feature to get it into the top left 9 times?

[image: example]

Comment: If you mean is there a way to automate it, then not really.  You could do it a bit more efficiently though. Type one letter, use snapping, and duplicate the text boxes, then type the letters. [an example](https://imgur.com/8nhfOuC)